# How to select outer pl.col when using .filter inside .with_columns?

Tags: python-polars

In my Polars LazyFrame, I want to divide some of the values in a `price` column by the mean of the `price` values of the same month.

I figured I could use `.filter` within `.with_columns` sort of as follows:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('need_ratio').eq(1))
      .then(pl.col('price') / df.filter(pl.col('datetime').dt.month() == pl.col('datetime').dt.month()).get_column('price').mean())
      .otherwise(pl.col('price'))
      .alias('price')
)
```

But of course the pl.col inside `.filter` will only point to the columns of my filtered LazyFrame, not the 'outer' LazyFrame that I use `.with_columns` on.

How do I change the code such that instead of `pl.col('datetime').dt.month()` on both sides of the equation in the filter condition, one of the sides points to the column value of my outer LazyFrame?

Comment: reproducible example with expected output please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use a `pl.when` conditional to either bring
a raw value from another column, or normalize that raw value by a monthly average.

You do not need to manually filter at all! Instead, you’ll want to use a
[window operation (via `.over()`)](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/).
From here all of the values you’re interested in are lined up and you can
use a regular division operation to get the new value:

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col
from datetime import date, timedelta
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(0)
size = 200

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date':  pl.datetime_range(start := date(2000, 1, 1), end=start + timedelta(days=size-1), interval='1D', eager=True),
    'price': rng.uniform(100, 300, size=size),
    'need_ratio': rng.choice([0, 1], size=size)
})


result = (
    df.with_columns(
        month_avg_price=col('price').mean().over(col('date').dt.month())
    )
    .with_columns(
        new_price=(
            pl.when(col('need_ratio').eq(1))
            .then(col('price') / col('month_avg_price')).otherwise(col('price'))
        )
    )
)

print(result)
# shape: (200, 5)
# ┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────┐
# │ date                ┆ price      ┆ need_ratio ┆ month_avg_price ┆ new_price  │
# │ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---             ┆ ---        │
# │ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ i64        ┆ f64             ┆ f64        │
# ╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════════╪════════════╡
# │ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 227.392337 ┆ 1          ┆ 207.864582      ┆ 1.093945   │
# │ 2000-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 153.957343 ┆ 0          ┆ 207.864582      ┆ 153.957343 │
# │ 2000-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 108.194705 ┆ 1          ┆ 207.864582      ┆ 0.520506   │
# │ 2000-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 103.305527 ┆ 0          ┆ 207.864582      ┆ 103.305527 │
# │ …                   ┆ …          ┆ …          ┆ …               ┆ …          │
# │ 2000-07-15 00:00:00 ┆ 101.281777 ┆ 0          ┆ 204.128712      ┆ 101.281777 │
# │ 2000-07-16 00:00:00 ┆ 254.52984  ┆ 1          ┆ 204.128712      ┆ 1.246909   │
# │ 2000-07-17 00:00:00 ┆ 295.653143 ┆ 0          ┆ 204.128712      ┆ 295.653143 │
# │ 2000-07-18 00:00:00 ┆ 217.974006 ┆ 1          ┆ 204.128712      ┆ 1.067826   │
# └─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Of course, we don’t need an explicit dependent column and can rewrite out
query to the below:

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import col
from datetime import date, timedelta
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng(0)
size = 200

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date':  pl.datetime_range(start := date(2000, 1, 1), end=start + timedelta(days=size-1), interval='1D', eager=True),
    'price': rng.uniform(100, 300, size=size),
    'need_ratio': rng.choice([0, 1], size=size)
})

month_avg_price = col('price') / col('price').mean().over(col('date').dt.month())
result = (
    df.with_columns(
        pl.when(col('need_ratio').eq(1))
        .then(month_avg_price).otherwise(col('price'))
        .alias('new_price')
    )
)

print(result)
# shape: (200, 4)
# ┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
# │ date                ┆ price      ┆ need_ratio ┆ new_price  │
# │ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
# │ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ i64        ┆ f64        │
# ╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
# │ 2000-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 227.392337 ┆ 1          ┆ 1.093945   │
# │ 2000-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 153.957343 ┆ 0          ┆ 153.957343 │
# │ 2000-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 108.194705 ┆ 1          ┆ 0.520506   │
# │ 2000-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 103.305527 ┆ 0          ┆ 103.305527 │
# │ …                   ┆ …          ┆ …          ┆ …          │
# │ 2000-07-15 00:00:00 ┆ 101.281777 ┆ 0          ┆ 101.281777 │
# │ 2000-07-16 00:00:00 ┆ 254.52984  ┆ 1          ┆ 1.246909   │
# │ 2000-07-17 00:00:00 ┆ 295.653143 ┆ 0          ┆ 295.653143 │
# │ 2000-07-18 00:00:00 ┆ 217.974006 ┆ 1          ┆ 1.067826   │
# └─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Do note that the data in the `new_price` column are heterogeneous in interpretation,
depending on the value of `need_ratio` some values are ratios compared to the
monthly average whereas others are raw values.